# Launching bash file exits after first command with "Terminated" message while it runs well within terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am on Ubuntu 22.04 platform.
I made a simple push button GUI in c named `t2s` and placed it in `~/.local/bin` whose path is added to `PATH` environment variable. While I am pressing down the button, it is recording voice from mic to a temp file. When I release the button GUI exits.
I run the following line which works well within terminal:

```
 t2s && notify-send -u normal  -t 10000 "$( whispercpp -m /home/****/Desktop/2022-10/whisper.cpp/models/ggml-small.bin -nt -l tr -f /dev/shm/mic.wav )"
```

Voice is sent to `whispercpp` speech to text engine and transcribed. The result is shown in the notification on the screen.

But when I place that line in a file and launch it, such as:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 t2s && notify-send -u normal  -t 10000 "$( whispercpp -m /home/****/Desktop/2022-10/whisper.cpp/models/ggml-small.bin -nt -l tr -f /dev/shm/mic.wav )"

 exit 0
```

it only executes the GUI button, when the GUI exits after releasing button, it doesn't execute

```
 notify-send -u normal  -t 10000 "$( whispercpp -m /home/****/Desktop/2022-10/whisper.cpp/models/ggml-small.bin -nt -l tr -f /dev/shm/mic.wav )"
```

part

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I also tried it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

t2s
TEXT=$( whispercpp -m /home/****/Desktop/2022-10/whisper.cpp/models/ggml-small.bin -nt -l tr -f /dev/shm/mic.wav )"
notify-send -u normal  -t 10000 $TEXT
```

Nothing's changed.

**EDIT:**

I noticed that it's related to shell internals.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81520/how-to-suppress-terminated-message-after-killing-in-bash
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551713/how-can-i-silence-the-terminated-message-when-my-command-is-killed-by-timeout
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65902/why-does-bash-show-terminated-after-killing-a-process

I still don't know how to overcome it.

Comment: I would get rid of the `&&` and break the single line into 3 lines. First line: `t2s`. Second line: `TEXT=$( whispercpp -m /home/****/Desktop/2022-10/whisper.cpp/models/ggml-small.bin -nt -l tr -f /dev/shm/mic.wav )"`. Third line: `notify-send -u normal  -t 10000 $TEXT`. I would also check the location of the temp `mic.wav` file.

Comment: @user68186 thank you for responding. I tried it before but I did it again, unfortunately it fails.

Comment: Let's try `echo $TEXT` after second line, before the `notify-send ...` line. Let me know if you see any text in the terminal resembling the recorded audio.

Comment: @user68186 I've just tried it. It exits right after `t2s` with `Terminated` message. It appears to be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81520/how-to-suppress-terminated-message-after-killing-in-bash

Answer (score 0):

After reading the following links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175647/is-it-possible-to-detect-which-trap-signal-in-bash/2183063#2183063
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360201/how-do-i-kill-background-processes-jobs-when-my-shell-script-exits
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70609841/how-to-catch-sigint-within-a-bash-subshell

I understood that termination of `ffmpeg` line which was executed within `GUI button` causes bash shell to terminate after `t2s` GUI.
I worked around the issue by chatching up `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM` signals within a `trap` block and then I placed the rest of the commands in it after `t2s`:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap_with_arg() { # from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2183063/804678
  local func="$1"; shift
  for sig in "$@"; do
    trap "$func $sig" "$sig"
  done
}

stop() {
  trap - SIGINT EXIT
  printf '\n%s\n' "received $1, killing child processes"
  notify-send -u normal  -t 10000 "$(whispercpp -m /home/**/Desktop/2022-10/whisper.cpp/models/ggml-small.bin -nt -l tr -f /dev/shm/mic.wav )"
  kill -s SIGINT 0
}

trap_with_arg 'stop' EXIT SIGINT SIGTERM SIGHUP

t2s

exit 0
```